# Does Excel have in-cell formula for multiple strings in a cell?

Tags: string, excel-formula

I have a bunch of names in a column - Mike, Bob, Al, John, Fred, Jim, etc.

Does Excel have some sort of include or find that I can combine in an IF statement to tag only the guys I need?

If I find the names I need then enter some code like BD, otherwise blank.

Something like this:

=IF(EXISTS("Mike","John","Bob", A1),"BD","")

so if the A1 cell has Mike, John, or Bob, then the target cell equals BD, otherwise nothing.

thanks,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any such "Exists" function, but you could use something like this:

IF(OR(A1="Mike", A1="John", A1="Bob"),"BD","")

Answer (score 0):

this will tell you if the cell contains "Mike".

```
=IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mike",A1))),"BD","")
```

You could repeat this function inside itself for however many names you need to check against. This one will tell you if the cell contains Mike or John

```
=IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mike",A1))),"BD",IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("John",A1))),"BD",""))
```